# How to draw a polygon for masking in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I need an tensorflow alternative of a PILLOW ImageDraw.Polygon as a part of tensorflow graph ( gradients are not needed). I have corners of a parallelogram and need to use this parallelogram as a binary mask to fill with zeroes anything except the area inside the parallelogram. Coping between gpu and cpu to use the pillow is extremely slow. Any way to draw it with tensorflow? Or on gpu? Any lib?

Comment: Not sure I would tag with `python-imaging-library` if you specifically don't want that as a solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
def fill(A, B, fill_below_or_right=True, resolution = (800, 480), meshGrid = None, tfMode = False):
    xs, ys = resolution
    if (tfMode):
        # select whether, >=0 is True, or, <=0 is True, to determine whether to
        # fill above or below the line
        op = tf.math.greater_equal if fill_below_or_right else tf.math.less_equal
        op_rev = tf.math.less_equal if fill_below_or_right else tf.math.greater_equal
        close_op = tf.experimental.numpy.allclose
    else:
        op = np.greater_equal if fill_below_or_right else np.less_equal
        close_op = np.allclose

    if(meshGrid is None):
        Y, X = np.mgrid[0:ys, 0:xs]
        if (tfMode): # Just cache X, Y tuple and pass as a meshGrid to make is fast
            Y = cast_f32(tf.convert_to_tensor(Y))
            X = cast_f32(tf.convert_to_tensor(X))
    else:
        Y, X = meshGrid

    if(close_op(B[0], A[0])): #X = A
        a = B[0]
        return op(X, a)
    elif(close_op(B[1], A[1])): #Y = A
        a = B[1]
        return op(Y, a)
    else:
        m = (B[1]-A[1])/(B[0]-A[0]) # m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) = slope

    # the equation for a line is y = m*x + b, so calculate
    # m and b from the two points on the line
    b = A[1] - m*A[0]           # b = y1 - m*x1 = y intercept

    # for each points of the grid, calculate whether it's above, below, or on
    # the line. Since y = m*x + b, calculating m*x + b - y will give
    # 0 when on the line, <0 when above, and >0 when below
    L = m*X + b - Y
    if m < 1.0:
        return op_rev(L, 0.0)
    else:
        return op(L, 0.0)

def draw_quad(pts, resolution = (800, 480), meshGrid = None, tfMode = False):
    pts = [cast_f32(item) for item in pts]
    x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = pts


    r = fill((x0, y0), (x1, y1), True, resolution, meshGrid, tfMode) & \
        fill((x1, y1), (x2, y2), False, resolution, meshGrid, tfMode) & \
        fill((x2, y2), (x3, y3), False, resolution, meshGrid, tfMode) & \
        fill((x3, y3), (x0, y0), True, resolution, meshGrid, tfMode)


    return r
```